# Where can I get JSF 2.1 prose document?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, broken-links

I tried to download from the [official Oracle page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/) the JSF 2.0 prose document. Unluckily, the link is broken. I searched on Google without success. Do you know where I can find the doc?

PS: in reality, I use Mojarra 2.1.7, so I'll need the 2.1.7 prose document.
PPS: also [this link](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2_1-mrel2-oth-JSpec/) seems broken.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra

Comment: @kolossus "prose" documents are the specs?